# "command not found" when calling Puppet on Centos 7

Tags: puppet, centos7

I have an installed puppet on my Centos 7 and I can't make a normal call.

```
puppet --help
-bash: puppet: command not found
```

but when trying to call from the path I got a response:

```
/opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet --help

Usage: puppet <subcommand> [options] <action> [options]
Available subcommands:

  agent             The puppet agent daemon
  apply             Apply Puppet manifests locally
```

Could be the path problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

puppet is not in the PATH variable

For an individual user, add it to the .bashrc file like this

```
export PATH=/opt/puppetlabs/bin/:$PATH
```